# Make all users within the domain a member of a security group

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Using either Powershell or VBS, how can I make all of the users within my domain **who have an email address** a member of a specific security group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 import ActiveDirectory
 $Group = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -eq "GroupName"}
 Get-ADUser -filter {EmailAddress -like "*"} | % {Add-ADGroupMember $Group $_}
```